# How to open a new view from a Fragment?

Tags: android, view, fragment

I have a fragment with a list of lessons:

[image]

I want when I click the first option to open a new view.
How I can do that?

Below is the code from the fragment in the image

```
public class FirstYearFragment extends Fragment {  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

        // Create a list of words
        final ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        words.add(new Word(R.string.firstYearDirection, R.string.algevra, R.drawable.algevra));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.firstYearDirection, R.string.arxaia, R.drawable.arxaia));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.firstYearDirection, R.string.ekuesi, R.drawable.ekthesi));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.firstYearDirection, R.string.geometria, R.drawable.geometry));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.firstYearDirection, R.string.fysiki, R.drawable.fusiki));
        words.add(new Word(R.string.firstYearDirection, R.string.xhmeia, R.drawable.xhmeia));

        // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
        // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
        WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(getActivity(), words, R.color.category_first_year);

        // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
       // word_list.xml layout file.
       ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

Comment: I use the below but I am getting error                                                                                                    
                                                                           
                               listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FirstYearForumView.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to declare it to Manifest.

Problem solved.